# AnyChart 8.4.2: Server error during getting Base64 chart string

Tags: anychart

I'm using `getPngBase64String` for getting Base64 string of my charts. This function sends request to the AnyChart's server. During this request I got this error:
[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VgLJ.png)

And text version:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://export.anychart.com/png. No 'Acces-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mysite.domain' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 504.

How I can fix this error? It's a new one, I used this feature for years and hadn't any issues before.

Comment: Can you please check it again? Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @AnyChartSupport No, I haven't. And it's weird, because yesterday it was definitely.

Comment: The root problem is that you’re getting a 504 error. That’s the problem you need to solve. Even if 504 error had the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, it’d still be a 504 error instead of a success response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker ok, good. But how I can solve this? I cannot impact on internal AnyChart requests. And I haven't any changes on my domain.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be split in two distinct cases: The 504 error and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.
While the first one indicates the lack of response from the server in the set period of time and could be solved by extending the timeout gate.
The second one could indicate that the server that you’ve sent your request to was not set-up to allow cross-origin requests. Seems that this was a one-time issue and won’t re-appear, as it couldn’t be recreated in our recent tests.
You can also think of setting up your own export server to avoid using one maintained by AnyChart, this can give you more control over availability and CORS.